# My application say, too many connections but the db connection is not full

Tags: spring, database, mariadb, mybatis

My application say,

```
Error querying database. Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Too many connections
```

But DB connection is not full.
I use spring and mybatis and mariaDB. what is the problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfWeH.png)

Comment: The database doesn't allow more connections, increase the connections or use a proper connection pool.

Comment: What do `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections'` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Max_used_connections'` say?

If both show the same value then at some point indeed all available connections were used up

Comment: SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections': 65    and
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Max_used_connections': 68
what's the problem?